# Module not found: Can't resolve './reducers/index'

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux, reducers

Module not found: Can't resolve './reducers/index' in'C:\Users\Dibba\Desktop\rdx\src'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

node version is
v9.11.2
npm version is
6.9.1-next.0

structure:

[image]

error message :

[image]

code:

[image]

Comment: Hi! To make questions more accessible for search engines, screen readers etc., please copy and paste your source code and directory listings as text.

Answer (score 5):

Your app is not able to find your root reducer since the file name on disk doesn't match the file name in the code. There appears to be a trailing space in the filename of `./reducers/index.js`, from what I can see in your first screenshot. Remove the space and your app should be able to find the file without problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the /index from the directory './reducers/index' and set it to './reducers'. It should work.

If the above does not work for you, check the steps below.

Make sure the reducers folder is created in the 'src' directory and create a file named index.js in the reducers folder.